# Accessing parent's key in firebase bolt

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We can access the current locations key using `key()`. I want to access the key of the parent(or some ancestor) of current location in the bolt file. So, is there something like `this.parent().key()`(this does not seem to work) for doing so?

Example: If I want to create the following in the rules json file:

```
....
"a":{
  "$x": {
    "$y":{
      ".validate": "data.isNumber() && y.length + x.length < data.val()"
    }
  }
}
....
```

The ".bolt" file would look like this:

```
....
"a":ABC[]
....
type ABC extends XYZ[] { }
type XYZ extends Number {
  validate() { key().length + ???.length < this }
}
```

So, what do I replace ??? in the file with? (should be something like `this.parent().key()`)